# How to highlight a rows and columns intersection in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create school schedule. I have 2 sheets: 1st with time, room and lesson and 2nd with time and room that are used right now.  I have a problem with highlighting cells in the 2nd sheet. I don't understand which formula I should use for conditional formatting.

For example:

[image: Schedule (room, time and lesson)]

[image: Result that I want to get in 2nd sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the slot times exactly and the schedule is on a different sheet from the results, you need to use indirect:

```
=countifs(indirect("Schedule!$A$2:$A$6"),$A2,indirect("Schedule!$B$2:$B$6"),B$1)
```

[image]

If you want to see which slots have an overlap with any of the lessons on the schedule, it is a different and much harder (though do-able) question.